# How to use Interceptor.Dll in C# and Kinect SDK to send keypresss event to DirectX Games?

Tags: c#, kinect, keypress

I want to send Keyboard key events to DirectX Games using Kinect.

I am using C# + Kinect SDK,
I have tried interception.dll wrapper.

But I cannot implement Interception in my C# code.

Here is my Code where I am getting error:

```
  Input input = new Input();
  input.KeyboardFilterMode = KeyboardFilterMode.All;
  input.Load();

  input.SendKeys(Keys.Up,KeyState.Down);

  input.Unload();
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this just mean that they want you to reference the `Interceptor` explicitly?

Comment: Can you please let me know how to refer Interceptor explicitly ?

Or can you suggest a alternate way to send keypress events to directX Game via C# ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Right, I'm pretty sure this is a conflict because the IDE doesn't know if you're referring to `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` or `Interceptor.Keys` what you can do is either remove `System.Windows.Forms` from your using namespace statements, this is a bad idea though. The second option is to explicitly reference `Interceptor.Keys` this is as easy as replacing your `Keys` statements with `Interceptor.Keys` instead.